# How to parse XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, minidom

I have an XML retrieved from NOAA and I am trying to parse it using minidom in Python, but I am not able to retrieve the values.

```
 `<parameters applicable-location="point1">
  <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n7-1">
    <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
    <value>75</value>
    <value>67</value>
    <value>65</value>
    <value>72</value>
    <value>65</value>
    <value>64</value>
    <value>62</value>
  </temperature>
</parameters>
```

`

I need to retrieve the values under tag maximum temperature.

Comment: You could trim that example down to a smaller test set. But more importantly, you need to post the code you already have. We cannot suggest fixes to code that we cannot see.

Comment: Further to @tdelaney: read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [BeautifulpSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) is an easy way.

You can try. like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

XML_STRING = """
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
  <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n7-1">
    <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
    <value>75</value>
    <value>67</value>
    <value>65</value>
    <value>72</value>
    <value>65</value>
    <value>64</value>
    <value>62</value>
  </temperature>
</parameters>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(XML_STRING, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('value'):
    print(tag.string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with libxml. Here is how to do proper setup tested for ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev lib32z1-dev python-dev -y
pip install lxml
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Replace `python-dev` with `python3-dev` if you are using python3. You can parse xml as follows:

```
file_content = """your xml string here"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, "xml")
max_temp_list = [int(item.string) for item in soup.find("temperature", {"type": "maximum"}).findAll("value")]
print(max_temp_list)
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for further examples of finding elements.